Как сделать пункты меню с выгнутостью наружу?
Подскажите как добиться вот такого эффекта у активного элемента меню

У меня, к сожалению, получается только вот так


https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkML640BcoA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zJkV0DIXeY
https://codepen.io/Qwertiy/pen/NWJRZXm?editors=1100


:root {
  --body-bg: #123;
  --nav-bg: #234;
  
  font-size: 10px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: system-ui;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  background: var(--body-bg);
  padding-inline-start: 20rem;
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: sandybrown;
}

a:hover {
  color: lightcoral;
}

nav {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, silver, var(--nav-bg));
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-block: 2rem;
  overflow: auto;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.nav-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;   
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.nav-list a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-block: 1rem;
  padding-inline: 2rem;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.nav-list li {
  margin-inline: 1rem 0;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100vw 0 0 100vw;
}

.nav-list li:is(.active, :hover, :focus-within) {
  background: var(--body-bg);
}

.nav-list li:is(.active, :hover, :focus-within)::before,
.nav-list li:is(.active, :hover, :focus-within)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  right: 0rem;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: 10em solid var(--body-bg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.nav-list li:is(.active, :hover, :focus-within)::before {
  bottom: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 50% 100%);
}

.nav-list li:is(.active, :hover, :focus-within)::after {
  top: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 0%, 50% 0%);
}
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" aria-current="page">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">And another</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>




Можно использовать псевдо-элементы ::before и ::after. И задать им фон через radial-gradient. Примерно так:
.nav-item__active {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-item__active::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at left bottom, transparent 70%, red 70%);
}

